# How can I run SUMIF or COUNTIF with two Conditions?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function, countif

I recently got some great [help with `SUMIF` and `COUNTIF`](https://superuser.com/a/478992/46516) and ended up with the following, working formulas;

```
=SUMIF(REC!$F:$F,$C2,REC!$G:$G)
=COUNTIF(REC!$F:$F,$C2)
```

I had been mixing up the syntax and swapping the sum range with the criteria range.

Now I am trying to sum up and count the instances where a given vendor `F` is contracted by a location `Q`. Unfortunately, trying to add `-IFS` to these is not working out. My expectation was that the following would work;

```
=SUMIFS(REC!$F:$F,$C2,REC!$G:$G,REC!$Q:$Q,$G$2)
=COUNTIFS(REC!$F:$F,$C2,REC!$Q:$Q,$G$2)
```

So,

- the SUMIFS formula is testing (`REC!$F:$F,$C2,REC!$G:$G`) and (`REC!$F:$F,REC!$Q:$Q,$G$2`)
- the COUNTIFS formula is testing (`REC!$Q:$Q,$G$2`) and (`REC!$F:$F,$C2`)

The REC! sheet is a listing of vendor projects with the following fields: `REC!F` column and the `C` column contain vendor IDs; `G,H` is fees, hours for each project; `REC!Q` is the column containing the designated location. Some of the rows on the REC! sheet are blank in the `F,G,H` columns.

Am I, yet again, bumbling the syntax in the `SUMIFS` and `COUNTIFS` forumlas? Is there a simpler way using `SUMPRODUCT`? Would I be better off importing to Access?

---

I have also tried using [array style formulas](https://superuser.com/q/206200/46516),

```
{=SUMIF(REC!$F:$F,$C5,REC!$G:$G)*AND(REC!$Q:$Q,$G$2)}
{=SUMIFS(REC!$F:$F,$C2, REC!$G:$G, REC!$Q:$Q, $G$2)}
```

But they all issue [#VALUE!] errors and have evaluations like [0,0,0,0,0....].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see your data so take this with a grain of salt, but if you are entering the formulas as they appear above, the issue is the syntax - you're going to have to swap again :) `SUMIF` takes `range, criteria, sum_range`, while `SUMIFS` takes `sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria_1, etc.`. That being the case, try this for the `SUMIFS`:

```
=SUMIFS(REC!$G:$G,REC!$F:$F,$C2,REC!$Q:$Q,$G$2)
```

This assumes that `REC!$G:$G` is what you want to sum. As for the `COUNTIFS`, what error are you getting? Your syntax looks correct.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! The COUNTIFS *was* correct, it was referring to a null set and wasn't returning a value, but I couldn't tell until I had the SUMIFS working.

Comment: No prob! Happy it helped (I'd be lying if I said that syntax shift hadn't messed me up a few times as well).